# RoR: Shell/System commands with write property not working in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

`System("ls")`
`System("pwd")`

Both these commands just work fine in both production & development mode on the same server.

However `System("mkdir test")` or any other command that involves creating a new file/dir does not go through in production mode, but works just fine in development mode. Any ideas here?

My guess is it has something to do with permissions but not sure where.

Comment: On the server, in the directories you're creating artifacts in, under the user your server runs as.

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your server you should have a `user` different from `root` for security reasons. Than this `user` should be added to `sudoers` list:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/7477/how-can-i-add-a-new-user-as-sudoer-using-the-command-line

now, **depending where you want to create this folder**, if it's in your app folder where your user has permissions to read/write, (search `chmod 755` and `chown` to set the owner of the folder, better use `chown -R` to apply this to all subfolders), after this you'll be able to create that folder with:

```
System("mkdir test")
```

but only in folders where your user has access to read/write.

If you want to create the test folder in some other path where you need to use `sudo` you'll have to run:

```
System("sudo mkdir test")
```

normally this is running in a background and you won't be there to write the password, so you'll have to add your command to not require password while running sudo, with `NOPASSWD` directive you can do that:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/159007/how-do-i-run-specific-sudo-commands-without-a-password

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers #!important visudo, read in the upper link more about it before trying this.
```

after doing all this you'll be able to create a folder in your path using:

```
System("sudo mkdir test")
```

without requiring a password.

Comment: in your local machine you are the owner of that folder and you can run that command as you have read/write permissions for it. On server you should run ls -la to see what permissions you have and who owns the folder

Comment: My development setup is also on the same server and not on a local machine & the user is root in both modes. the folder is owned by root with perms drwxr-xr-x 17

Comment: recently built an app that clone one origin app and start it on another subdomain, had to use  sudo commands a few times,in your case I think it's just a matter of ownership of the folder in where you want to create a directory.

Comment: ok, I'll be back in a few hours, hopefully you'll fix it by then. If not I'll try to help you more with this when I'll be online

Comment: @user2186138 **You should not be running your web app as root.**